# Derived class function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived

```
class Base
{
   protected: 
      int data;
   public:
      virtual int getData() { return data; }
      virtual void setData(int value) { data = value; }
};

class Child : protected Base
{
   public:
   void setData(int value)
   {
       Base::setData(value);
       cout << "Data is set.\n";
   }
};

class Worker
{
   private:
      Child obj;
   public:
      void setGlobalData(int val)
      {
         obj.setData(val); // This is normal
      }

      int getGlobalData()
      {
         return obj.getData();  // Line 140, Error
      }
};
```

Error during compiling of file with Worker class:

```
Base.hpp: In member function ‘int Worker::getGlobalData()’:
Base.hpp:22:19: error: ‘virtual int Base::getData()’ is inaccessible
Worker.cpp:140:34: error: within this context
Worker.cpp:140:34: error: ‘Base’ is not an accessible base of ‘Child’
```

Comment: If getData() has no definition in the base, that could very well be the root of your issue.

Comment: I fixed one of you `virtual` declarations but I'm with GMan - if this is your code you are missing a definition for `Base::getData()`

Comment: Sorry, `Base::getData()` is available. I added it. I can't show the real code cause it's big.

Comment: Then my only comments are my guess, which I posted as an answer, and that `getData` should be `const`.

Comment: Life is too short to waste on bad questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually make it a public base class?

```
//            vvvvvv important
class Child : public Base
```

Otherwise it's private, and you get errors similar to what you have, namely:

> ‘Base’ is not an accessible base of ‘Child’

Comment: Yeah, sorry. There was `protected`. But if I need to hide the `int data`. I don't want to make public inheritance.

Comment: @Ockonal I think you misunderstand the access modifiers when subclassing. If `int data` is private in the base class, `public`, `protected`, and `private` inheritance do not modify that. It is always `private` to the class that it's a member of.

Comment: And If I'll make int data as protected there is still error (with protected inheritance).

Comment: @Ockonal: That specified what access users of the class have with respect to the base. The base's specifiers say what access users of that class have to it's members. Regardless of whether or not users can access `Child`'s `Base`, `Base::data` is still `protected`. Changing it to my code should be the only change. If not, please post the new errors/more code. Have you a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
class Base
{
   protected: 
      int data;
   public:
      virtual int getData() {return data;}
      virtual void setData(int value) { data = value; }
};

class Child : public Base
{
   public:
   void setData(int value)
   {
       Base::setData(value);
       cout << "Data is set.\n";
   }
};

class Worker
{
   private:
      Child obj;
   public:
      void setGlobalData(int val)
      {
         obj.setData(val); // This is normal
      }

      int getGlobalData()
      {
         return obj.getData();
      }
};
```

Comment: One problem, your `Base.getData()` class never returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

`class Worker`  not `clas Worker`

In `Worker` class, `obj.setData(val);` is attempting to access a private member of `Child` class.

Comment: I doubt his code actually has that. `virtual` is also typo'd for `Base::setData`

Answer (score 0):

Except for clas -> class and virtua -> virtual your code is perfectly fine. There is absolutely nothing wrong with it. Since literally this doesn't compile because of the typos I suspect your original code was a bit different in that the derivation of `Child` from `Base` was private or that `getData` was private.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current existing version of the code has `Child` subclassing `Base` via `protected`  inheritance, the `public` functions in `Base` become `protected` in `Child`, so `Worker` can not access them via `Child` object.

Answer (score 0):

Class `Child` inherits class `Base` as `protected`, so the member function `Child::getData()` is not publically accessible to clients of `Child`.

As everyone else here said, changing the inheritance of `Base` to `public` is one way to fix it.

```
class Child: public Base
```

Also note that casting your `Child` object to type `Base` also makes the function `Base::getData()` of the object publically accessible.

```
return static_cast<Base *>(&obj)->getData();
```